# vector copy constructor C++ : does it have to be linear time?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector containing objects of type STL map, and I do `vector.push_back(some map)`.

This unfortunately calls the map copy constructor, and wastes a lot of time. I understand that i can get around this by keeping a vector of (smart) pointers to maps - but this got me wondering - I read that STL anyway keeps its data on the heap and not on the stack - so why is the copy ctor not `O(1)` time, by simply copying pointers?

Comment: Should you question title be "**map** copy constructor"?

Comment: If you simply copy pointers, your new map will be pointing to the exact same internal data as the original, which isn't always what you want...

Comment: The problem you're referring to can be easily addressed since C++11, with the introduction of "move constructors".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need the original map anymore after pushing back a copy back into the vector, write:

```
some_vector.push_back(std::move(some_map));
```

If you don't have a C++11 compiler yet, add an empty map and then swap that with the original:

```
some_vector.resize(some_vector.size() + 1);
some_vector.back().swap(some_map);
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly: to do that, it would have to start with some sort of copy on write mechanism -- when you put something into a vector, it's required to be a copy of the original (or at least act like one). For example, if I push a map onto my vector, and then remove an item from the original map, that item should still be there in the copy of the map that was pushed onto the vector.

Then it would have to keep track of all the pointers, and ensure that the pointee (the map in this case) remained valid until all those pointers were themselves destroyed. It's certainly possible to do that. Quite a few languages, for example, provide garbage collection largely for this reason. Most of those change the semantics of things, so when/if you (for example) create a vector of maps, putting a map into the vector has reference semantics -- i.e., when you modify the original map, that's supposed to change any "copies" of it that you put into other collections.

As you've observed, you can do any/all of the above in C++ if you really want. The reason it doesn't right now is that most of the C++ standard library is built around value semantics instead of reference semantics. Either is (IMO, anyway) a perfectly valid and reasonable approach -- some languages take one, others take the other. Either/both can work just fine, but value semantics happens to be the choice that was made in C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy pointers, create a `vector` of pointers to `map`. You can do that.

```
std::vector<std::map<A,B>* > x;
```

It doesn't do this automatically because it can't know who you want to manage the memory. Should the objects of the `map` be destroyed when the `vector` goes out of scope. What if the original `map` is still in scope?

Comment: Heap objects don't have scope. Scope only applies to names.